# DC-DC converter connected wrong?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I bought a [Traco Power TSR 1-24120 DC-DC converter](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/000156677DS02/datenblatt-156677-tracopower-tsr-1-24120-dcdc-wandler-print-24-vdc-12-vdc-1-a-6-w-anzahl-ausgaenge-1-x.pdf) to convert 24V to 12V to power a [Noctua fan](https://noctua.at/en/products/fan/nf-a6x25-flx/specification) to it, but it seems to have blown up instantly.

I have no output voltage and the first time I turned the power on, the fan just did a little 'twitch'.

This is how I connected it:

[image]

I used the left connecter as input and the right one as output

I obviously did something wrong, but what?

**EDIT**

- After checking the polarity of the connectors I discovered that the ones on the converter and source are correct, but the one on the fan was wrong.
- The input voltage is at 24.49V
- I got the converter directly from Conrad.

Comment: Also, which 12V fan was connected?  Model and datasheet could help.  Please click the [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/611157/edit) link to add this information, thank you.

Comment: What is the input and which connector? Show the markings on the converter and what polarity are the wires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fans basically are BLDC motors that apply a pulsed load with a swept frequency starting from DC. As such storage capacitance is often necessary to prevent unstable regulator function. Up to 470 uF is allowed. Your connections are logically correct. The fan's start surge current will be much greater than the steady-state current.

You need to evaluate if there is any stability/compatibility issues driving a fan load.  If there is a next time try testing with fixed R load. Then test with an NPN sink to the load to ramp the current up slower and look for output instability by monitoring input/output current and Vout with Vfan.

Comment: I talked to the Noctua support and asked if this converter would be overloaded with the power on current of the fan, but they declined. So I guess I missed the connectors up initially. I have bought another converter now which also has a potentiometer to adjust the voltage. thank you.

Comment: You need at least a 2A supply not 1000 mA for startup, unless you had a dimmer.. the pot if not wire wound rated for 2W will melt. Use fixed 2W R's or better run 2 fans in series with a current limiting R